# The linux boot message in dmesg doesn't output to uart

Tags: linux, stdout, uart

My problem is my linux is success for boot but there is no more boot message output to uart(ttyPS0) after "Starting kernel...".

[image: booting image]

As you can see in the pic, there is a lot of boot message in dmesg but they are not showing when linux was booting.

The bootargs is passed by uEnv.txt:

```
bootcmd=run adi_sdboot
adi_sdboot=echo Copying Linux from SD to RAM... && fatload mmc 0 0x3000000 ${kernel_image} && fatload mmc 0 0x2A00000 ${devicetree_image} && if fatload mmc 0 0x2000000 ${ramdisk_image}; then bootm 0x3000000 0x2000000 0x2A00000; else bootm 0x3000000 - 0x2A00000; fi
bootargs=console=ttyPS0,115200 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rw earlyprintk debug rootfstype=ext4 rootwait
fdt_high=0x2D000000
```

I have tested whether ttyPS0 is working properly and dmesg shows that it has registered.
[image: dmesg | grep tty]

Also, it can be echo.
[image: ttyPS0 test]

I doubt if it's the console problem.
[image: console not found]

Or I just missing the CONFIG which I don't know?

---------------------------------Update--------------------------------------

Since I change the linux kernel to the success version.

I think the problem is console setting.
Here is the boot message in the success version linux.
You can see console has been set to ttyPS0 at 0.7sec.

```
U-Boot 2019.01-gf736b0f-dirty (Feb 17 2021 - 15:27:50 +0800)

CPU:   Zynq 7z035
Silicon: v3.1
Model: MTI Phased Antenna platform...
DRAM:  ECC disabled 1 GiB
MMC:   mmc@e0100000: 0
Loading Environment from SPI Flash... SF: Detected n25q256a with page size 256 Bytes, erase size 4 KiB, total 32 MiB
OK
In:    serial@e0001000
Out:   serial@e0001000
Err:   serial@e0001000
Net:   ZYNQ GEM: e000b000, phyaddr c, interface rgmii-id
eth0: ethernet@e000b000
405 bytes read in 6 ms (65.4 KiB/s)
Importing environment from SD ...
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0
Copying Linux from SD to RAM...
3704008 bytes read in 214 ms (16.5 MiB/s)
11887 bytes read in 14 ms (829.1 KiB/s)
** Unable to read file uramdisk.image.gz **
## Booting kernel from Legacy Image at 03000000 ...
   Image Name:   Linux-4.14.0-xilinx-g42d8052-dir
   Image Type:   ARM Linux Kernel Image (uncompressed)
   Data Size:    3703944 Bytes = 3.5 MiB
   Load Address: 00008000
   Entry Point:  00008000
   Verifying Checksum ... OK
## Flattened Device Tree blob at 02a00000
   Booting using the fdt blob at 0x2a00000
   Loading Kernel Image ... OK
   Loading Device Tree to 2cffa000, end 2cfffe6e ... OK

Starting kernel ...

[    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0
[    0.000000] Linux version 4.14.0-xilinx-g42d8052-dirty (jazz.chou@mtisdi) (gcc version 6.2.1 20161114 (Linaro GCC Snapshot 6.2-2016.11)) #3 SMP PREEMPT Tue Mar 30 17:51:20 CST 2021
[    0.000000] CPU: ARMv7 Processor [413fc090] revision 0 (ARMv7), cr=18c5387d
[    0.000000] CPU: PIPT / VIPT nonaliasing data cache, VIPT aliasing instruction cache
[    0.000000] OF: fdt: Machine model: hases-Array-Controller with Zynq Platform (Z-7035)
[    0.000000] Memory policy: Data cache writealloc
[    0.000000] cma: Reserved 700 MiB at 0x01000000
[    0.000000] On node 0 totalpages: 262144
[    0.000000] free_area_init_node: node 0, pgdat c0935180, node_mem_map ef69a000
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 1536 pages used for memmap
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 0 pages reserved
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 196608 pages, LIFO batch:31
[    0.000000]   HighMem zone: 65536 pages, LIFO batch:15
[    0.000000] random: fast init done
[    0.000000] percpu: Embedded 16 pages/cpu @ef670000 s35084 r8192 d22260 u65536
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: s35084 r8192 d22260 u65536 alloc=16*4096
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: [0] 0 [0] 1
[    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 260608
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: console=ttyPS0,115200 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rw earlyprintk debug rootfstype=ext4 rootwait
[    0.000000] PID hash table entries: 4096 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
[    0.000000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 131072 (order: 7, 524288 bytes)
[    0.000000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 6, 262144 bytes)
[    0.000000] Memory: 312124K/1048576K available (5120K kernel code, 215K rwdata, 1472K rodata, 1024K init, 150K bss, 19652K reserved, 716800K cma-reserved, 262144K highmem)
[    0.000000] Virtual kernel memory layout:
[    0.000000]     vector  : 0xffff0000 - 0xffff1000   (   4 kB)
[    0.000000]     fixmap  : 0xffc00000 - 0xfff00000   (3072 kB)
[    0.000000]     vmalloc : 0xf0800000 - 0xff800000   ( 240 MB)
[    0.000000]     lowmem  : 0xc0000000 - 0xf0000000   ( 768 MB)
[    0.000000]     pkmap   : 0xbfe00000 - 0xc0000000   (   2 MB)
[    0.000000]     modules : 0xbf000000 - 0xbfe00000   (  14 MB)
[    0.000000]       .text : 0xc0008000 - 0xc0600000   (6112 kB)
[    0.000000]       .init : 0xc0800000 - 0xc0900000   (1024 kB)
[    0.000000]       .data : 0xc0900000 - 0xc0935d80   ( 216 kB)
[    0.000000]        .bss : 0xc0935d80 - 0xc095b644   ( 151 kB)
[    0.000000] Preemptible hierarchical RCU implementation.
[    0.000000]  RCU restricting CPUs from NR_CPUS=4 to nr_cpu_ids=2.
[    0.000000]  Tasks RCU enabled.
[    0.000000] RCU: Adjusting geometry for rcu_fanout_leaf=16, nr_cpu_ids=2
[    0.000000] NR_IRQS: 16, nr_irqs: 16, preallocated irqs: 16
[    0.000000] efuse mapped to f0800000
[    0.000000] slcr mapped to f0802000
[    0.000000] L2C: platform modifies aux control register: 0x72360000 -> 0x72760000
[    0.000000] L2C: DT/platform modifies aux control register: 0x72360000 -> 0x72760000
[    0.000000] L2C-310 erratum 769419 enabled
[    0.000000] L2C-310 enabling early BRESP for Cortex-A9
[    0.000000] L2C-310 full line of zeros enabled for Cortex-A9
[    0.000000] L2C-310 ID prefetch enabled, offset 1 lines
[    0.000000] L2C-310 dynamic clock gating enabled, standby mode enabled
[    0.000000] L2C-310 cache controller enabled, 8 ways, 512 kB
[    0.000000] L2C-310: CACHE_ID 0x410000c8, AUX_CTRL 0x76760001
[    0.000000] zynq_clock_init: clkc starts at f0802100
[    0.000000] Zynq clock init
[    0.000011] sched_clock: 64 bits at 333MHz, resolution 3ns, wraps every 4398046511103ns
[    0.000033] clocksource: arm_global_timer: mask: 0xffffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0x4ce07af025, max_idle_ns: 440795209040 ns
[    0.000063] Switching to timer-based delay loop, resolution 3ns
[    0.000163] clocksource: ttc_clocksource: mask: 0xffff max_cycles: 0xffff, max_idle_ns: 537538477 ns
[    0.000198] timer #0 at f080a000, irq=17
[    0.000683] Console: colour dummy device 80x30
[    0.000710] Calibrating delay loop (skipped), value calculated using timer frequency.. 666.66 BogoMIPS (lpj=3333333)
[    0.000728] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
[    0.000873] Mount-cache hash table entries: 2048 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
[    0.000890] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 2048 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
[    0.001444] CPU: Testing write buffer coherency: ok
[    0.001648] CPU0: thread -1, cpu 0, socket 0, mpidr 80000000
[    0.040353] Setting up static identity map for 0x100000 - 0x100060
[    0.060313] Hierarchical SRCU implementation.
[    0.100312] smp: Bringing up secondary CPUs ...
[    0.170656] CPU1: thread -1, cpu 1, socket 0, mpidr 80000001
[    0.170767] smp: Brought up 1 node, 2 CPUs
[    0.170786] SMP: Total of 2 processors activated (1333.33 BogoMIPS).
[    0.170795] CPU: All CPU(s) started in SVC mode.
[    0.171754] devtmpfs: initialized
[    0.174641] VFP support v0.3: implementor 41 architecture 3 part 30 variant 9 rev 4
[    0.174948] clocksource: jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 19112604462750000 ns
[    0.174971] futex hash table entries: 512 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
[    0.209069] pinctrl core: initialized pinctrl subsystem
[    0.210393] NET: Registered protocol family 16
[    0.222379] DMA: preallocated 256 KiB pool for atomic coherent allocations
[    0.223651] cpuidle: using governor menu
[    0.230644] hw-breakpoint: found 5 (+1 reserved) breakpoint and 1 watchpoint registers.
[    0.230660] hw-breakpoint: maximum watchpoint size is 4 bytes.
[    0.230784] zynq-ocm f800c000.ocmc: ZYNQ OCM pool: 256 KiB @ 0xf0840000
[    0.231207] zynq-pinctrl 700.pinctrl: zynq pinctrl initialized
[    0.231672] e0000000.serial: ttyPS1 at MMIO 0xe0000000 (irq = 25, base_baud = 6249999) is a xuartps
[    0.232248] e0001000.serial: ttyPS0 at MMIO 0xe0001000 (irq = 26, base_baud = 6249999) is a xuartps
**[    0.753431] console [ttyPS0] enabled**
[    0.772447] vgaarb: loaded
[    0.775590] SCSI subsystem initialized
[    0.779539] media: Linux media interface: v0.10
[    0.785151] Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[    0.789847] pps_core: LinuxPPS API ver. 1 registered
[    0.794834] pps_core: Software ver. 5.3.6 - Copyright 2005-2007 Rodolfo Giometti <giometti@linux.it>
[    0.804019] PTP clock support registered
[    0.807986] EDAC MC: Ver: 3.0.0
[    0.811660] FPGA manager framework
[    0.815283] fpga-region fpga-full: FPGA Region probed
[    0.821481] clocksource: Switched to clocksource arm_global_timer
[    0.837146] NET: Registered protocol family 2
[    0.842198] TCP established hash table entries: 8192 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
[    0.849336] TCP bind hash table entries: 8192 (order: 4, 65536 bytes)
[    0.855946] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 8192 bind 8192)
[    0.862415] UDP hash table entries: 512 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
[    0.868367] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 512 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
[    0.874922] NET: Registered protocol family 1
[    0.879616] RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
[    0.885570] RPC: Registered udp transport module.
[    0.890261] RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
[    0.894985] RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
[    0.901421] PCI: CLS 0 bytes, default 64
[    0.905858] hw perfevents: no interrupt-affinity property for /pmu@f8891000, guessing.
[    0.913984] hw perfevents: enabled with armv7_cortex_a9 PMU driver, 7 counters available
[    0.923882] workingset: timestamp_bits=30 max_order=18 bucket_order=0
[    0.931009] jffs2: version 2.2. (NAND) (SUMMARY)  © 2001-2006 Red Hat, Inc.
[    0.938890] bounce: pool size: 64 pages
[    0.942749] io scheduler noop registered
[    0.946665] io scheduler deadline registered
[    0.950981] io scheduler cfq registered (default)
[    0.955792] io scheduler mq-deadline registered
[    0.960319] io scheduler kyber registered
[    0.966769] dma-pl330 f8003000.dmac: Loaded driver for PL330 DMAC-241330
[    0.973504] dma-pl330 f8003000.dmac:         DBUFF-128x8bytes Num_Chans-8 Num_Peri-4 Num_Events-16
[    0.982783] uartlite 43c40000.uartlite_0: No serial alias passed. Using the first free id
[    0.990954] uartlite 43c40000.uartlite_0: Checking id 0
[    0.996278] 43c40000.uartlite_0: ttyUL0 at MMIO 0x43c40000 (irq = 46, base_baud = 0) is a uartlite
[    1.014136] brd: module loaded
[    1.024416] loop: module loaded
[    1.029832] m25p80 spi0.0: SPI-NOR-UniqueID 10447300199200051c0020008a8eb87c57
[    1.037374] m25p80 spi0.0: n25q256a (32768 Kbytes)
[    1.042222] 6 ofpart partitions found on MTD device spi0.0
[    1.047701] Creating 6 MTD partitions on "spi0.0":
[    1.052522] 0x000000000000-0x0000000e0000 : "qspi-fsbl-uboot"
[    1.059193] 0x0000000e0000-0x000000100000 : "qspi-uboot-env"
[    1.065749] 0x000000100000-0x000000600000 : "qspi-linux"
[    1.072011] 0x000000600000-0x000000620000 : "qspi-device-tree"
[    1.078696] 0x000000620000-0x000001300000 : "qspi-rootfs"
[    1.084957] 0x000001300000-0x000002000000 : "qspi-bitstream"
[    1.092039] libphy: Fixed MDIO Bus: probed
[    1.098599] CAN device driver interface
[    1.142310] libphy: MACB_mii_bus: probed
[    1.148821] macb e000b000.ethernet eth0: Cadence GEM rev 0x00020118 at 0xe000b000 irq 28 (aa:99:75:dd:1d:61)
[    1.158696] TI DP83867 e000b000.ethernet-ffffffff:0c: attached PHY driver [TI DP83867] (mii_bus:phy_addr=e000b000.ethernet-ffffffff:0c, irq=POLL)
[    1.172061] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 3.2.6-k
[    1.177882] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2015 Intel Corporation.
[    1.184986] i2c /dev entries driver
...
Mount failed for selinuxfs on /sys/fs/selinux:  No such file or directory
[    1.914702] init: hwclock main process (648) terminated with status 1
 * Setting up X socket directories...                                    [ OK ]
 * STARTDISTCC is set to false in /etc/default/distcc
 * /usr/bin/distccd not starting
pidof: can't get program name from /proc/1569/stat

 * Not starting NFS kernel daemon: no support in current kernel.
 * Starting IIO Daemon iiod                                              [ OK ]

Last login: Wed Mar 31 10:25:51 CST 2021 from 172.16.250.61 on pts/1
Welcome to Linaro 14.04 (GNU/Linux 4.14.0-xilinx-g42d8052-dirty armv7l)

 * Documentation:  https://wiki.analog.com/ https://ez.analog.com/

root@sdi01:~#
```

And these are boot message show by wrong kernel.

```
U-Boot 2019.01-gf736b0f-dirty (Feb 17 2021 - 15:27:50 +0800)

CPU:   Zynq 7z035
Silicon: v3.1
Model: MTI Phased Antenna platform...
DRAM:  ECC disabled 1 GiB
MMC:   mmc@e0100000: 0
Loading Environment from SPI Flash... SF: Detected n25q256a with page size 256 Bytes, erase size 4 KiB, total 32 MiB
OK
In:    serial@e0001000
Out:   serial@e0001000
Err:   serial@e0001000
Net:   ZYNQ GEM: e000b000, phyaddr c, interface rgmii-id
eth0: ethernet@e000b000
405 bytes read in 6 ms (65.4 KiB/s)
Importing environment from SD ...
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0
Copying Linux from SD to RAM...
3828064 bytes read in 231 ms (15.8 MiB/s)
11887 bytes read in 14 ms (829.1 KiB/s)
** Unable to read file uramdisk.image.gz **
## Booting kernel from Legacy Image at 03000000 ...
   Image Name:   Linux-5.4.0-xilinx-g282eb80-dirt
   Image Type:   ARM Linux Kernel Image (uncompressed)
   Data Size:    3828000 Bytes = 3.7 MiB
   Load Address: 00008000
   Entry Point:  00008000
   Verifying Checksum ... OK
## Flattened Device Tree blob at 02a00000
   Booting using the fdt blob at 0x2a00000
   Loading Kernel Image ... OK
   Loading Device Tree to 2cffa000, end 2cfffe6e ... OK

Starting kernel ...


Last login: Wed Mar 31 10:50:00 CST 2021 from 172.16.49.210 on pts/0
Welcome to Linaro 14.04 (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-xilinx-g282eb80-dirty armv7l)

 * Documentation:  https://wiki.analog.com/ https://ez.analog.com/

root@sdi01:~#
```

And here is it's dmesg

```
root@sdi01:~# dmesg
[    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0
[    0.000000] Linux version 5.4.0-xilinx-g282eb80-dirty (jazz.chou@mtisdi) (gcc version 6.2.1 20161114 (Linaro GCC Snapshot 6.2-2016.11)) #27 SMP PREEMPT Wed Mar 31 09:45:50 CST 2021
[    0.000000] CPU: ARMv7 Processor [413fc090] revision 0 (ARMv7), cr=18c5387d
[    0.000000] CPU: PIPT / VIPT nonaliasing data cache, VIPT aliasing instruction cache
[    0.000000] OF: fdt: Machine model: hases-Array-Controller with Zynq Platform (Z-7035)
[    0.000000] Memory policy: Data cache writealloc
[    0.000000] cma: Reserved 700 MiB at 0x01000000
[    0.000000] On node 0 totalpages: 262144
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 1536 pages used for memmap
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 0 pages reserved
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 196608 pages, LIFO batch:63
[    0.000000]   HighMem zone: 65536 pages, LIFO batch:15
[    0.000000] percpu: Embedded 15 pages/cpu s31820 r8192 d21428 u61440
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: s31820 r8192 d21428 u61440 alloc=15*4096
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: [0] 0 [0] 1
[    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 260608
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: console=ttyPS0,115200 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rw earlyprintk debug rootfstype=ext4 rootwait
[    0.000000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 131072 (order: 7, 524288 bytes, linear)
[    0.000000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 6, 262144 bytes, linear)
[    0.000000] mem auto-init: stack:off, heap alloc:off, heap free:off
[    0.000000] Memory: 310180K/1048576K available (6144K kernel code, 168K rwdata, 1596K rodata, 1024K init, 1136K bss, 21596K reserved, 716800K cma-reserved, 262144K highmem)
[    0.000000] rcu: Preemptible hierarchical RCU implementation.
[    0.000000] rcu:     RCU restricting CPUs from NR_CPUS=4 to nr_cpu_ids=2.
[    0.000000]  Tasks RCU enabled.
[    0.000000] rcu: RCU calculated value of scheduler-enlistment delay is 10 jiffies.
[    0.000000] rcu: Adjusting geometry for rcu_fanout_leaf=16, nr_cpu_ids=2
[    0.000000] NR_IRQS: 16, nr_irqs: 16, preallocated irqs: 16
[    0.000000] efuse mapped to (ptrval)
[    0.000000] slcr mapped to (ptrval)
[    0.000000] L2C: platform modifies aux control register: 0x72360000 -> 0x72760000
[    0.000000] L2C: DT/platform modifies aux control register: 0x72360000 -> 0x72760000
[    0.000000] L2C-310 erratum 769419 enabled
[    0.000000] L2C-310 enabling early BRESP for Cortex-A9
[    0.000000] L2C-310 full line of zeros enabled for Cortex-A9
[    0.000000] L2C-310 ID prefetch enabled, offset 1 lines
[    0.000000] L2C-310 dynamic clock gating enabled, standby mode enabled
[    0.000000] L2C-310 cache controller enabled, 8 ways, 512 kB
[    0.000000] L2C-310: CACHE_ID 0x410000c8, AUX_CTRL 0x76760001
[    0.000000] random: get_random_bytes called from start_kernel+0x268/0x41c with crng_init=0
[    0.000000] zynq_clock_init: clkc starts at (ptrval)
[    0.000000] Zynq clock init
[    0.000010] sched_clock: 64 bits at 333MHz, resolution 3ns, wraps every 4398046511103ns
[    0.000033] clocksource: arm_global_timer: mask: 0xffffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0x4ce07af025, max_idle_ns: 440795209040 ns
[    0.000064] Switching to timer-based delay loop, resolution 3ns
[    0.000705] Console: colour dummy device 80x30
[    0.000740] Calibrating delay loop (skipped), value calculated using timer frequency.. 666.66 BogoMIPS (lpj=3333333)
[    0.000758] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
[    0.000957] Mount-cache hash table entries: 2048 (order: 1, 8192 bytes, linear)
[    0.000977] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 2048 (order: 1, 8192 bytes, linear)
[    0.001754] CPU: Testing write buffer coherency: ok
[    0.001794] CPU0: Spectre v2: using BPIALL workaround
[    0.002042] CPU0: thread -1, cpu 0, socket 0, mpidr 80000000
[    0.060255] Setting up static identity map for 0x100000 - 0x100060
[    0.080205] rcu: Hierarchical SRCU implementation.
[    0.120206] smp: Bringing up secondary CPUs ...
[    0.200594] CPU1: thread -1, cpu 1, socket 0, mpidr 80000001
[    0.200603] CPU1: Spectre v2: using BPIALL workaround
[    0.200757] smp: Brought up 1 node, 2 CPUs
[    0.200771] SMP: Total of 2 processors activated (1333.33 BogoMIPS).
[    0.200780] CPU: All CPU(s) started in SVC mode.
[    0.201339] devtmpfs: initialized
[    0.204893] VFP support v0.3: implementor 41 architecture 3 part 30 variant 9 rev 4
[    0.205318] clocksource: jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 19112604462750000 ns
[    0.205342] futex hash table entries: 512 (order: 3, 32768 bytes, linear)
[    0.245307] pinctrl core: initialized pinctrl subsystem
[    0.246528] NET: Registered protocol family 16
[    0.248652] DMA: preallocated 256 KiB pool for atomic coherent allocations
[    0.249997] cpuidle: using governor menu
[    0.258363] hw-breakpoint: found 5 (+1 reserved) breakpoint and 1 watchpoint registers.
[    0.258377] hw-breakpoint: maximum watchpoint size is 4 bytes.
[    0.258521] zynq-ocm f800c000.ocmc: ZYNQ OCM pool: 256 KiB @ 0x(ptrval)
[    0.259144] e0000000.serial: ttyPS1 at MMIO 0xe0000000 (irq = 24, base_baud = 6249999) is a xuartps
[    0.259728] e0001000.serial: ttyPS0 at MMIO 0xe0001000 (irq = 25, base_baud = 6249999) is a xuartps
[    0.269195] vgaarb: loaded
[    0.269625] SCSI subsystem initialized
[    0.269943] pps_core: LinuxPPS API ver. 1 registered
[    0.269955] pps_core: Software ver. 5.3.6 - Copyright 2005-2007 Rodolfo Giometti <giometti@linux.it>
[    0.269989] PTP clock support registered
[    0.270031] EDAC MC: Ver: 3.0.0
[    0.270603] FPGA manager framework
[    0.271597] clocksource: Switched to clocksource arm_global_timer
[    0.281765] thermal_sys: Registered thermal governor 'step_wise'
[    0.282093] NET: Registered protocol family 2
[    0.282784] tcp_listen_portaddr_hash hash table entries: 512 (order: 0, 6144 bytes, linear)
[    0.282825] TCP established hash table entries: 8192 (order: 3, 32768 bytes, linear)
[    0.282931] TCP bind hash table entries: 8192 (order: 4, 65536 bytes, linear)
[    0.283078] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 8192 bind 8192)
[    0.283182] UDP hash table entries: 512 (order: 2, 16384 bytes, linear)
[    0.283236] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 512 (order: 2, 16384 bytes, linear)
[    0.283468] NET: Registered protocol family 1
[    0.284075] RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
[    0.284088] RPC: Registered udp transport module.
[    0.284097] RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
[    0.284105] RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
[    0.284121] PCI: CLS 0 bytes, default 64
[    0.284736] hw perfevents: no interrupt-affinity property for /pmu@f8891000, guessing.
[    0.284964] hw perfevents: enabled with armv7_cortex_a9 PMU driver, 7 counters available
[    0.286492] workingset: timestamp_bits=30 max_order=18 bucket_order=0
[    0.287499] jffs2: version 2.2. (NAND) (SUMMARY)  \xffffffc2\xffffffa9\xffffffa9 2001-2006 Red Hat, Inc.
[    0.287774] bounce: pool size: 64 pages
[    0.287796] io scheduler mq-deadline registered
[    0.287807] io scheduler kyber registered
[    0.288216] zynq-pinctrl 700.pinctrl: zynq pinctrl initialized
[    0.291331] dma-pl330 f8003000.dmac: Loaded driver for PL330 DMAC-241330
[    0.291351] dma-pl330 f8003000.dmac:         DBUFF-128x8bytes Num_Chans-8 Num_Peri-4 Num_Events-16
[    0.292146] uartlite 43c40000.uartlite_0: No serial alias passed. Using the first free id
[    0.292162] uartlite 43c40000.uartlite_0: Checking id 0
[    0.292245] 43c40000.uartlite_0: ttyUL0 at MMIO 0x43c40000 (irq = 46, base_baud = 0) is a uartlite
[    0.302259] brd: module loaded
[    0.311663] loop: module loaded
[    0.313613] spi-nor spi0.0: SPI-NOR-UniqueID 10447300199200051c0020008a8eb87c57
[    0.313631] spi-nor spi0.0: found n25q256ax1, expected n25q256a
[    0.313955] spi-nor spi0.0: n25q256ax1 (32768 Kbytes)
[    0.314018] 6 fixed-partitions partitions found on MTD device spi0.0
[    0.314029] Creating 6 MTD partitions on "spi0.0":
[    0.314043] 0x000000000000-0x0000000e0000 : "qspi-fsbl-uboot"
[    0.321572] 0x0000000e0000-0x000000100000 : "qspi-uboot-env"
[    0.331167] 0x000000100000-0x000000600000 : "qspi-linux"
[    0.332712] 0x000000600000-0x000000620000 : "qspi-device-tree"
[    0.334218] 0x000000620000-0x000001300000 : "qspi-rootfs"
[    0.341605] 0x000001300000-0x000002000000 : "qspi-bitstream"
[    0.351996] libphy: Fixed MDIO Bus: probed
[    0.353096] CAN device driver interface
[    0.354423] libphy: MACB_mii_bus: probed
[    0.770619] TI DP83867 e000b000.ethernet-ffffffff:0c: attached PHY driver [TI DP83867] (mii_bus:phy_addr=e000b000.ethernet-ffffffff:0c, irq=POLL)
[    0.770644] macb e000b000.ethernet eth0: Cadence GEM rev 0x00020118 at 0xe000b000 irq 27 (aa:99:75:dd:1d:61)
[    0.771007] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 3.2.6-k
[    0.771017] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2015 Intel Corporation.
[    0.772095] i2c /dev entries driver
[    0.773324] cdns-wdt f8005000.watchdog: Xilinx Watchdog Timer with timeout 10s
[    0.773664] EDAC MC: ECC not enabled
[    0.773852] Xilinx Zynq CpuIdle Driver started
[    0.774335] sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
[    0.774345] sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
[    0.774353] sdhci-pltfm: SDHCI platform and OF driver helper
[    0.810218] mmc0: SDHCI controller on e0100000.sdhci [e0100000.sdhci] using ADMA
[    0.810636] ledtrig-cpu: registered to indicate activity on CPUs
[    0.810866] clocksource: ttc_clocksource: mask: 0xffff max_cycles: 0xffff, max_idle_ns: 537538477 ns
[    0.811037] timer #0 at (ptrval), irq=40
[    0.812987] axi_sysid 43c80000.axi-sysid-0: AXI System ID core version (1.01.a) found
[    0.813169] axi_sysid 43c80000.axi-sysid-0: [VKU0_L01] [sys rom custom string placeholder] on [X03PA] git branch <master> git <36b40b9583905cf886c4f1b15685b4b4e0f83578> clean [2021-03-17 01:43:55] UTC
[    0.813812] fpga_manager fpga0: Xilinx Zynq FPGA Manager registered
[    0.814529] NET: Registered protocol family 10
[    0.815737] Segment Routing with IPv6
[    0.815843] sit: IPv6, IPv4 and MPLS over IPv4 tunneling driver
[    0.816591] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[    0.816613] can: controller area network core (rev 20170425 abi 9)
[    0.816682] NET: Registered protocol family 29
[    0.816695] can: raw protocol (rev 20170425)
[    0.816705] can: broadcast manager protocol (rev 20170425 t)
[    0.816720] can: netlink gateway (rev 20190810) max_hops=1
[    0.817090] Registering SWP/SWPB emulation handler
[    0.828568] hctosys: unable to open rtc device (rtc0)
[    0.828583] of_cfs_init
[    0.828691] of_cfs_init: OK
**[    0.829022] Warning: unable to open an initial console.**
[    0.829265] Waiting for root device /dev/mmcblk0p2...
[    0.852554] mmc0: new high speed SDHC card at address aaaa
[    0.863276] mmcblk0: mmc0:aaaa SC16G 14.8 GiB
[    0.878214]  mmcblk0: p1 p2 p3
[    0.895177] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    0.895250] VFS: Mounted root (ext4 filesystem) on device 179:2.
[    0.903222] devtmpfs: mounted
[    0.906895] Freeing unused kernel memory: 1024K
[    0.921886] Run /sbin/init as init process
[    1.010577] random: fast init done
[    1.195747] random: init: uninitialized urandom read (12 bytes read)
[    1.320142] init: hwclock main process (48) terminated with status 1
[    1.487392] random: mountall: uninitialized urandom read (12 bytes read)
[    2.399692] systemd-udevd[144]: starting version 204
[    2.564875] random: lsb_release: uninitialized urandom read (24 bytes read)
[    4.795052] init: idmapd main process (368) terminated with status 1
[    4.795139] init: idmapd main process ended, respawning
[    5.508193] init: Failed to open system console: No such device
[    5.514923] init: Failed to open system console: No such device
```

There is no "console [ttyPS0] enabled" but "WARNING: unable to open an initial console" at 0.8sec.

I have try remove the /dev/console and remake by mdnod but it did not work.

How can I fix it?

Comment: I have thought serial console is `ttySx`, eg. `ttyS0` for first serial port. At least this is how my x86 supermicro machine works.

Comment: Sorry but I can't see much in the picture. If you have text, post text, not pictures. Regarding your question, not everything in the kernel message buffer goes to the console. This is configured by `kernel.printk`; see https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/kernel.txt.

Comment: Please sure about your log level , i refer you to check this guide https://elinux.org/Debugging_by_printing

Comment: I have try adding loglevel=8 in the bootargs too, still don't work.

Comment: Now I swap to use previous version linux kernel which it has boot message show at boot time. And it looks like there is something makes console go wrong. PS does not use the loglevel label and kernel.printk is 4 4 1 7 which is the same value as wrong one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the answer in Xilinx forum.

It is indeed a problem with the console.

https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Embedded-Linux/quot-Warning-unable-to-open-an-initial-console-quot-Under/m-p/1117002

It seems that its kernel code has not been fully updated, which makes some new parameters not fully set.